# Shopee API to get products data doesn't seem to work anymore (it worked before)

Tags: python, json, scrapy, shopee

Here's a simple [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) spider that anyone can use for testing.

```
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser
import scrapy
import json

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test-spider"
    allowed_domains = ["shopee.ph"]

    shopee_cookies = '[{"name": "csrftoken", "value": "RvxBdTixvBfdTR3xfQwbcYippqz8jEbF", "domain": "shopee.ph", "path": "/", "expires": -1, "httpOnly": false, "secure": false, "sameSite": "Lax"}, {"name": "_gcl_au", "value": "1.1.1251411089.1692464842", "domain": ".shopee.ph", "path": "/", "expires": 1700240842, "httpOnly": false, "secure": false, "sameSite": "Lax"}, {"name": "SPC_SI", "value": "sTLbZAAAAABwY1ZrR1NNU+WdNgAAAAAAdzlCYXIyVVQ=", "domain": ".shopee.ph", "path": "/", "expires": 1692551246.336331, "httpOnly": true, "secure": true, "sameSite": "Lax"}, {"name": "_fbp", "value": "fb.1.1692464842990.689078803", "domain": ".shopee.ph", "path": "/", "expires": 1700240846, "httpOnly": false, "secure": false, "sameSite": "Lax"}, {"name": "SPC_R_T_IV", "value": "NnVEbThnRjREMnNMZVpGVQ==", "domain": ".shopee.ph", "path": "/", "expires": 1727024846.336348, "httpOnly": false, "secure": true, "sameSite": "Lax"}, {"name": "SPC_T_ID", "value": "fn/OKngQO3doGdfFGyo/6mzLiviELHkKEbWM9J+x/ezTl/baT96grQer6ILrYX9tj3Kqs71Jg+hCimaK/XauidJXrd6HdPd2Smbxbu/fEStjOJi5g9/ucMmbBwuyh5M6H3TOGdpUop/9Q/zdpNj6MyxZaODnNsT5XprfsQxjB5g=", "domain": ".shopee.ph", "path": "/", "expires": 1727024846.336355, "httpOnly": true, "secure": true, "sameSite": "Lax"}, {"name": "SPC_T_IV", "value": "NnVEbThnRjREMnNMZVpGVQ==", "domain": ".shopee.ph", "path": "/", "expires": 1727024846.336362, "httpOnly": true, "secure": true, "sameSite": "Lax"}, {"name": "SPC_F", "value": "jiOtuCSNUaap3U4BHHfzhDihWwFht32f", "domain": ".shopee.ph", "path": "/", "expires": 1727024843.162052, "httpOnly": false, "secure": true, "sameSite": "Lax"}, {"name": "REC_T_ID", "value": "dc8a2570-3eb2-11ee-ac9b-2cea7fce6c95", "domain": ".shopee.ph", "path": "/", "expires": 1727024843.16206, "httpOnly": true, "secure": true, "sameSite": "Lax"}, {"name": "SPC_R_T_ID", "value": "fn/OKngQO3doGdfFGyo/6mzLiviELHkKEbWM9J+x/ezTl/baT96grQer6ILrYX9tj3Kqs71Jg+hCimaK/XauidJXrd6HdPd2Smbxbu/fEStjOJi5g9/ucMmbBwuyh5M6H3TOGdpUop/9Q/zdpNj6MyxZaODnNsT5XprfsQxjB5g=", "domain": ".shopee.ph", "path": "/", "expires": 1727024846.33634, "httpOnly": false, "secure": true, "sameSite": "Lax"}, {"name": "_QPWSDCXHZQA", "value": "4a585493-a7a0-4f0e-d696-687295d3a4c3", "domain": "shopee.ph", "path": "/", "expires": 1692496379, "httpOnly": false, "secure": false, "sameSite": "Lax"}, {"name": "IDE", "value": "AHWqTUm1b5ZflCqDTn6cpHDjyoeqH6iLfXcCOOm4YNaP8CHTsAZ7F_Daq4-zO-bsGIk", "domain": ".doubleclick.net", "path": "/", "expires": 1727024843.787698, "httpOnly": true, "secure": true, "sameSite": "None"}, {"name": "AMP_TOKEN", "value": "%24NOT_FOUND", "domain": ".shopee.ph", "path": "/", "expires": 1692468444, "httpOnly": false, "secure": false, "sameSite": "Lax"}, {"name": "_ga", "value": "GA1.2.833255521.1692464843", "domain": ".shopee.ph", "path": "/", "expires": 1727024844.498551, "httpOnly": false, "secure": false, "sameSite": "Lax"}, {"name": "_gid", "value": "GA1.2.1347861977.1692464844", "domain": ".shopee.ph", "path": "/", "expires": 1692551244, "httpOnly": false, "secure": false, "sameSite": "Lax"}, {"name": "_dc_gtm_UA-61918643-6", "value": "1", "domain": ".shopee.ph", "path": "/", "expires": 1692464904, "httpOnly": false, "secure": false, "sameSite": "Lax"}, {"name": "shopee_webUnique_ccd", "value": "raj%2F3ukNopIWTrFjVLQeGA%3D%3D%7C1%2BjiV3ga9OlzuAELTZtedUY5BlP1ZNVH5ybZJx2D4KNA9dGTvtFakjnNZvR64zKNG6yBDfEXdabTE%2FRKow%3D%3D%7CsWIQ7u7pR4F3BD7E%7C08%7C3", "domain": "shopee.ph", "path": "/", "expires": 1692496381, "httpOnly": false, "secure": false, "sameSite": "Lax"}, {"name": "ds", "value": "065598fda3b7cca4e5e241e446a075e9", "domain": "shopee.ph", "path": "/", "expires": 1692496381, "httpOnly": false, "secure": false, "sameSite": "Lax"}, {"name": "SPC_EC", "value": "RTJYa2Q5WEV4UDNnN3VGWr68rFv1FRJEeVkpwAzlu09WhtwSxFE1cZlwpQYRhhR56REixPuKfekz6oioE4EaDK12bvALil+QZ5B0EfG42psIFWNDe1moiErTZndyu1502KUlh5+OQoUWCvm1XkVY+2Iy7Jk5qyPI2J655JeZwv0=", "domain": ".shopee.ph", "path": "/", "expires": 1727024846.336291, "httpOnly": true, "secure": true, "sameSite": "Lax"}, {"name": "SPC_ST", "value": ".ek1DVmo5aGJjaVBxcklYU5o4/3v/8ndPeV2/fwtzWYUh1kWOopWvn7SFoQXWuS37Rs+J+Ym7U8OwOG73JbiFRWyOOo1GhKBgwhUeeWfE+q9XPDZXACC33t7qphoBu5hyWvR/G+WkpSUbIkmGPzprCIvhw7Qwyt8UFxk/4bA+47QQQUiDcPfHIq/sJqmVMEqH3Al6nCTDeEh/JCDLALRvNQ==", "domain": ".shopee.ph", "path": "/", "expires": 1727024846.336324, "httpOnly": true, "secure": true, "sameSite": "Lax"}, {"name": "SPC_CLIENTID", "value": "amlPdHVDU05VYWFwgvlavxoisbqjmacw", "domain": ".shopee.ph", "path": "/", "expires": 1727024846.336374, "httpOnly": false, "secure": false, "sameSite": "Lax"}, {"name": "_ga_CB0044GVTM", "value": "GS1.1.1692464843.1.0.1692464846.57.0.0", "domain": ".shopee.ph", "path": "/", "expires": 1727024846.367333, "httpOnly": false, "secure": false, "sameSite": "Lax"}]'

    shopee_cookies = json.loads(shopee_cookies)

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            "https://shopee.ph/api/v4/pdp/get_pc?shop_id=237078553&item_id=6929743700",
            cookies=self.shopee_cookies,
            headers={"x-api-source":"pc","af-ac-enc-dat":"null"},
            callback=self.parse_item,
        )


    def parse_item(self,response):
        open_in_browser(response)
```

Feel free to test it out as I provided the cookies as well (because the cookies are needed). Now as you can see, this piece of code actually worked before, around early August 2023. I had challenges to make it work before but thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74333263/14425271) I managed to get the products data. You can even see my [comment there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73424180/scrape-shopee-api-v4/74333263#comment135421636_74333263). Here's an image I screenshot before proving that it did work around early August.

[image]

As you can see the data is there and works well. Thanks to the headers `{"x-api-source":"pc","af-ac-enc-dat":"null"}` that made it worked. However as of August 20, 2023 as I am typing this. It seems that it doesn't work anymore. I'm not sure why, but I think there's some changes with the API that has happened. I spent all day trying to figure out and play with the headers but no luck. All I got right now as a result is this.

**Output I am having right now:**

> {"is_customized":false,"is_login":true,"platform":0,"action_type":2,"error":90309999,"tracking_id":"24d95bd5-40e5-44cd-b30b-885711481170","report_extra_info":""}

Here is the actual product page [link](https://shopee.ph/Realme-C53-C55-C35-C21Y-C25Y-RealmeC11-2021-C25-C25S-C15-C12-C2-C17-C3-Realme8-Pro-8i-7i-5-5i-6i-Fashion-Electroplated-Maple-Leaf-Square-Plating-Soft-Silicone-Case-Meiting-i.237078553.6929743700?sp_atk=f0eb6655-bb0f-496e-abf3-b1fb07e318a2&xptdk=f0eb6655-bb0f-496e-abf3-b1fb07e318a2) I used for testing. You can see the API there when you do "Inspect Element" -> "Network" tab. Take note that the output I am having right now is the same one I had before I managed to implement [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74333263/14425271). But right now it's back at it again. So the question is, could there be a way to make it work again? I feel like it's something with the headers that I am not getting it right, but I am not sure how to figure it out and that is why I am seeking help right now as I am out of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in a comment on another article, it seems that the their anti-crawling method has changed.

If there is a problem with the api response, you can check the problem with the following procedure.

1. get full api request

```
curl 'https://shopee.ph/api/v4/pdp/get_pc?shop_id=237078553&item_id=6929743700' \
  -H '744a5de7:<value>' \
  -H 'authority:<value>' \
  -H 'accept:<value>' \
  -H 'accept-language:<value>' \
  -H 'af-ac-enc-dat:<value>' \
  -H 'af-ac-enc-sz-token:<value>' \
  -H $'afe5f082:<value> '\
  -H 'content-type:<value>' \
  -H 'cookie:<value>' \
  -H 'dd46895e:<value>' \
  -H 'referer:<value>' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua:<value>' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile:<value>' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform:<value>' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest:<value>' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode:<value>' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site:<value>' \
  -H 'sz-token:<value>' \
  -H 'user-agent:<value>' \
  -H 'x-api-source:<value>' \
  -H 'x-csrftoken:<value>' \
  -H 'x-requested-with:<value>' \
  -H 'x-sap-ri:<value>' \
  -H 'x-shopee-language:<value>' \
  -H 'x-sz-sdk-version:<value>' \
  --compressed
```

Unlike when I tried before, something was added.
random elements like 744a5de7, $afe5f082, dd46895e

2. check api expire time
   some api has expire time.
   Most have expiration times in minutes, but I've seen sites that expire in 10 seconds.

by test, the their api's expire time is 60~120 seconds.

so I need to get full api request evert 1minutes.

3. find the necessary header elements.
   by remove one line, I can find below elements are necessary.

```
  -H $'24d10ef2: \
  -H '5025235d: \
  -H '744a5de7:\
  -H 'af-ac-enc-dat:\
  -H 'cookie:\
  -H 'user-agent:\
  -H 'x-csrftoken:\
  -H 'x-sap-ri:\
```

random element, af-ac-enc-dat, cookie, user-agent, x-csrftoken, x-sap-ri
is necessary.

4. check changed value validate
   af-ac-enc-dat:null is this case.

It's amazing that this worked until early August.

When I tried, "af-ac-enc-dat" is a value client creates with cookies and time.
It should not be changed.
af-ac-enc-dat is made by cookies, cookies also can not change.

so you need to figure out

- how to make random 3 element's name and value
- how to make af-ac-enc-dat, x-csrftoken, x-sap-ri

It seems to me that you are getting it by logging in when you get the cookie.

In my experience, even if you scrape through a proxy, scraping fails after a certain period of time.

And when you access it, it says that abnormal traffic has been detected and slides to prove you're not a robot.

So I tried scraping with a non-login cookie.

Scraping was possible through multiple cookie sets and multiple proxies.

### conclusion

I tried very hard to scrape it,
but I couldn't get past the their ever-changing defenses.

So I gave up at early July.

I hope you can solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

i have an error too. already checked. i think they are changing the headers req. it looks like this

```
GET /api/v4/shop/get_products_tab_data?by=popular&country=ID&from_source=search&limit=50&offset=0&order=desc&shop_id=224781834&start_ts=1690041600&upstream=pdp HTTP/2
Host: shopee.co.id
Cookie: SPC_F=CLE38NzQuOfu72ZZK3Fbk7uSV4Rl0Om3; REC_T_ID=cbe26cbc-29fb-11ee-b7ba-f4ee08290b63; _gcl_au=1.1.2119733819.1690471447; _fbp=fb.2.1690471447353.1570533404; SPC_CLIENTID=Q0xFMzhOelF1T2Z1eyyrhwwxishawszz; _med=cpc; csrftoken=FE3h0UK9cUKTSpcXbrms3HaOuZQLI4y6; SPC_SI=tTLbZAAAAAA5dDM5MWZkVzVNhQAAAAAAa1Fnb3Njc0k=; _QPWSDCXHZQA=28c21620-bf64-4cbc-c3bb-768c09ddd94d; _gid=GA1.3.1329493720.1692587428; _gcl_aw=GCL.1692587441.EAIaIQobChMIrbCJv-PsgAMVf4FLBR3v_wQWEAAYASAAEgKW__D_BwE; _gac_UA-61904553-8=1.1692587442.EAIaIQobChMIrbCJv-PsgAMVf4FLBR3v_wQWEAAYASAAEgKW__D_BwE; SPC_P_V=Epj8h5wnEQ2sD4OURKKvdycouuCI2YHaEekG7u9ezsvZjWGjPUhg9DFetTavXFCO3C63OOwrXzWL3gx7VDRvGkixJ2mTfc0wMCLFgyaJR+LQkC4eHAmRDCMKtHmCQXgF7RGQD5PFFx7OUbXAnu1pAktVpve6NGOAmNre/519svI=; SPC_ST=.MU83cVROQjhGZURLbEttONiDXDjrLsd6vGNERy6F8f7m5LTefdR1H4zNcrAdW+VXk5rjEyEaPFJrUPnNEJF9aPcTfrS9nukBbsb7f2TWvCqSL14xvK4145VpW1935EAZ8y+TNM2Ii2NELgi9KzO/lsjyeJtM4bhHd9vpAhoZZ2KO9psk92WId+lPjpjNiJO03Q19o3Gldiqu/6uo3B/JYg==; SPC_U=1047715958; SPC_R_T_ID=pkA90hKsNpTPhCjad/aK1CSaQhpsMokArXQS2nqHnSaHqC/ct9z7kJ2SCT3qtALegWNHd6YnNt4cZgTOn+WGaEhBZGEKlLc/OTynALNC7IrPpFqcJasaF/DOKX8imMsEr+9Wnct0GJ77BzJIiYF3riCD8PuMnY05yOMIk5D4yew=; SPC_R_T_IV=UHVXbzB3MXhYMW1SUEdVVQ==; SPC_T_ID=pkA90hKsNpTPhCjad/aK1CSaQhpsMokArXQS2nqHnSaHqC/ct9z7kJ2SCT3qtALegWNHd6YnNt4cZgTOn+WGaEhBZGEKlLc/OTynALNC7IrPpFqcJasaF/DOKX8imMsEr+9Wnct0GJ77BzJIiYF3riCD8PuMnY05yOMIk5D4yew=; SPC_T_IV=UHVXbzB3MXhYMW1SUEdVVQ==; shopee_webUnique_ccd=9wlap15q38u%2FjyDqeMXhSw%3D%3D%7CZJYFYh7ffzXrGWxFVrISb4CSSzK9huoBudwqWNpox09%2BIx9P3SCcAlZk3OsGAXz5TLVKLpJ0a0iBycFR%7CQeZNQ4uANkX3tHiI%7C08%7C3; ds=76644e11d13873c9fe6a40f193246e70; _ga=GA1.1.2011873235.1690471457; _dc_gtm_UA-61904553-8=1; SPC_EC=RklXT0ZlZVA2SmNDaTBIQslEsqR691BJDKmMLa1HhAOn7CSTgdQMN47UZ11FxNpmCyIvU7bi0z4zj64SpXGi094UHX2jaE6xBmOYAkJYNhFUdS/dRHoI1mcdwpf9rVJ8+kK8og9iFWju20lnzu1cuWyqQXf60ZF9JcbK3lQvHNA=; _ga_SW6D8G0HXK=GS1.1.1692600956.8.1.1692600957.59.0.0
2495ee40: *GTT#ILZ,J*RgDF&)2Sth7u:Q
X-Sz-Sdk-Version: 2.9.2-2&1.4.1
94d942d2: W1+Q&gY<k'_qcBegg9t1Fo*q5FJ!f]'!H/Bbi&LJH\7M$L=]"p.F8/*q_!ZNU(E%'CkE'0R-3ps8iL[Nc&G44^P_@_C"ik0h7kT-lWVD"e/[>Z7X1YHj)2[`r\uj8A[XO3+]gHb#[5fKf70G\r%e:G6f$G3dPVl;)b)lbWSB^J`Kff9;/IeaQ(%b'+iLX)]Ku4D@?:u'0?*@*(%$[qb0Tf%J[Ug6fd`H+c!,k>P.Vkf!4q2*6,3>)KYh9eJ,:^?H=5iR1usTREU^.A-g\_%.NG6W9bt+?8`Q0BE(gTS%N/oQ5sfi!?V$9pdYBfOdh5Ltr,Q2ADr::L*%[LDd:L@W,X.%)b4l\LId@>G1mjFUrJ-cn
Content-Type: application/json
X-Api-Source: rweb
Accept: application/json
X-Sap-Ri: 7f0ae3643a8576b6061b7b3e6051550dd3d3ae970d1848a4
X-Shopee-Language: id
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Af-Ac-Enc-Dat: 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
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_2_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.3 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1
X-Csrftoken: FE3h0UK9cUKTSpcXbrms3HaOuZQLI4y6
4a12d42b: 1;fI>#8q*F>+W8`]Yi@Wr>rZ*
Af-Ac-Enc-Sz-Token: 9wlap15q38u/jyDqeMXhSw==|ZJYFYh7ffzXrGWxFVrISb4CSSzK9huoBudwqWNpox09+Ix9P3SCcAlZk3OsGAXz5TLVKLpJ0a0iBycFR|QeZNQ4uANkX3tHiI|08|3
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: https://shopee.co.id/vearst?shop=224781834&tab=1&upstream=search
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

hope it helps.

for now, the viable solution is you make a bunch of acc, then rotate it when it hits the rate limiter. give it 15-30 mins to cool down if all acc got rate-limit (in my case status code 418).

Comment: wait, so you managed to get the result with these headers?

Comment: yes. my strategy is using many accounts in rotation. and as @Giuk Kim said, you need to test/check the necessary header elements, because in the headers there are some tracker IDs to track crawling/scraping activities.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shopee mobile api instead, using

> **/api/v4/pdp/cart_panel/get**

For example in python:

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint

url = "https://mall.shopee.vn/api/v4/pdp/cart_panel/get"
data = {
    "item_id" : 20103528776,
    "shop_id" : 218993976,
    "quantity" : 1,
}

item_info = requests.post(url= url, json = data).json()

pprint(item_info)
```

And the output is a bit less informative compared to the original:

```
{'data': {'is_direct_buy_now_to_opc': True,
      'item': {'image': 'vn-11134207-7r98o-lkufiewkx39c85',
               'is_hide_stock': False,
               'is_official_shop': True,
               'item_has_size_recommendation': False,
               'item_id': 20103528776,
               'models': [{'is_selectable': True,
                           'model_id': 135798969787,
                           'name': '',
                           'price': {'range_max': -1,
                                     'range_min': -1,
                                     'single_value': 29900000000},
                           'price_before_discount': {'range_max': -1,
                                                     'range_min': -1,
                                                     'single_value': 59000000000},
                           'stock': 50,
                           'tier_index': [0]}],
               'overall_purchase_limit': {'order_max_purchase_limit': 0},
               'price': {'range_max': -1,
                         'range_min': -1,
                         'single_value': 29900000000},
               'price_before_discount': {'range_max': -1,
                                         'range_min': -1,
                                         'single_value': -1},
               'promotion_labels': {'is_live_streaming_ongoing': False,
                                    'is_live_streaming_price': False,
                                    'pre_order_text': '',
                                    'wholesale_text': ''},
               'shop_id': 218993976,
               'spl_channel_id': 0,
               'stock': 50,
               'tier_variations': [{'options': [{'image': '', 'name': ''}],
                                    'title': ''}],
               'tracking': {'brand': 'ROBOT',
                            'cat_id': 100013,
                            'categories': [{'catid': 100013,
                                            'display_name': 'Điện Thoại & '
                                                            'Phụ Kiện',
                                            'is_default_subcat': False,
                                            'no_sub': False},
                                           {'catid': 100075,
                                            'display_name': 'Phụ kiện',
                                            'is_default_subcat': False,
                                            'no_sub': False},
                                           {'catid': 100287,
                                            'display_name': 'Sạc dự phòng '
                                                            '& Pin',
                                            'is_default_subcat': False,
                                            'no_sub': False},
                                           {'catid': 100486,
                                            'display_name': 'Sạc dự phòng',
                                            'is_default_subcat': False,
                                            'no_sub': True}],
                            'name': 'Pin Sạc Dự Phòng 20000mAh ROBOT RT22 '
                                    'LED 2 Cổng Sạc Vào Micro/Type C & 2 '
                                    'Cổng Sạc Ra USB',
                            'price': 29900000000}},
      'method': 0,
      'selected_tiers': {'0': 0},
      'selected_variation': {'max_quantity': 801,
                             'model_id': 135798969787,
                             'price': {'range_max': -1,
                                       'range_min': -1,
                                       'single_value': 29900000000},
                             'price_before_discount': {'range_max': -1,
                                                       'range_min': -1,
                                                       'single_value': 59000000000},
                             'promotion_labels': {'is_live_streaming_ongoing': False,
                                                  'is_live_streaming_price': False,
                                                  'pre_order_text': '',
                                                  'wholesale_text': ''},
                             'quantity_in_cart': 0,
                             'recommend_voucher_result': {},
                             'stock': 801,
                             'tier_index': [0]},
      'show_cart_panel': False}}
```

Note that this is just a temporary solution. I don't know when that method will be changed

Comment: Hey Luna, that's amazing! Could you let me know which part of the application you found this endpoint in?

Comment: it does not work for me, it return a json which 'is_login' field is False, any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Shopee's development team has recently ramped up their anti-crawler measures. It took me several weeks of reverse engineering to "open" their API:

If you want to forge a request to their API, you need to figure out how to generate the following HTTP headers:

- af-ac-enc-dat
- af-ac-enc-sz-token
- x-csrftoken
- x-sap-access-f
- x-sap-access-s
- x-sap-access-t
- x-sap-ri
- x-sap-sec
- x-sz-sdk-version

`x-csrftoken` is the same as the cookie "csrftoken".

`af-ac-enc-dat`, `af-ac-enc-sz-token`, `x-sap-access-f`, `x-sap-access-s` and `x-sap-access-t` are provided by the Security SDK, found in the script like `https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/web-sdk/js/live/*.js`. It is accessible via the global variable `window.ssdk00oQOOooO00QoQO`. For example, you can get the SDK version by calling:

```js
window.ssdk00oQOOooO00QoQO(300, 100) // returns '3.4.1-2'
```

To understand what are the arguments to obtain the various HTTP header values, [put a breakpoint](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/breakpoints) in this function.

`x-sap-ri` and `x-sap-sec` are set by another script. You don't need to manually set them, just use the [fetch function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) as it's been [monkey patched](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) to automatically include these headers.

`x-sz-sdk-version` is a concatenation of the Security SDK version (obtainable as shown above) and the "Base SDK Util" version, which can be tricky to find directly. It's in the `https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-pcmall-live-sg/assets/*.js` script that includes the `createBaseSdkUtils` function definition, the version is identifiable by a regex `var version="([0-9.]+)"`:
[Base SDK Util version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqzNs.png)

Effectively scraping Shopee, especially at scale, demands web browser automation tools like [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/), alongside strategies like fingerprint injection and residential proxies. If you prefer a ready-to-use solution, you can use [my Apify scraper](https://apify.com/marc_plouhinec/shopee-api-scraper).